# ios UIImage going outside of UIImageView Border

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiimageview, uiimage

Here black border shows the Parent UIView of UIImageView and Red border showing UIImageView i'm downloading image from server but the image is going outside of the UIImageView area as shown in the image. I'm doing it programmatically any help would be very much appreciated. I'm adding code block below

[image]

```
let bottomView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x : 10, y: stackView.height, width: view.width * 0.75, height: view.width * 0.75 ))

view.addSubview(bottomView)

bottomView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
bottomView.layer.borderWidth = 1

bottomView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
bottomView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
bottomView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.bottomAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
bottomView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
bottomView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
bottomView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.width * 0.75).isActive = true
bottomView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.width * 0.75).isActive = true

let imageView : UIImageView = UIImageView(frame : CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 250 ))

 imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
 imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1
 bottomView.addSubview(imageView)

 imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
 imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
 imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
 imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive = true
 imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive = true
 imageView.downloadedFrom(link: (sizeResult?.results![0].data?.size_Chart?.mobile_image?.imageValue?.imageMain?.url)!, contentMode : .scaleAspectFill)
```

this bottomView will be added UIAlertViewController.

[This image shows ** contentMode  is Aspect Fit **](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tx97f.png)

Comment: have you set clips to bounds to true?

Comment: @MahendraGP i tried that but only half of the image was visible..

Comment: set contentMode to `aspect fit`

Comment: is your all constraints are proper....check log for breaking constraints, if any.

Comment: @ArnabHore it making image too small and left aligned

Comment: As per as I understand from your image, that your image has lots of white space at the right side... try to crop the image by any photo editing tool like preview and then use it, otherwise you have to shift the image to the right side of imageView by code or from storyboard...

Comment: @ArnabHore Thank you sir. I will check that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the properties of `uiimageview` and content mode:

```
self.imageView.clipsToBounds = true
self.imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use clip to bound with your image view, Definitely It will resolve your issue. 
Swift:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.bottomView.clipsToBounds = false
    self.imageView.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit**

**self.imageView.clipsToBounds = true**

it was worked for me..

Answer (score 0):

The last line of your code should be this -

```
imageView.downloadedFrom(link: (sizeResult?.results![0].data?.size_Chart?.mobile_image?.imageValue?.imageMain?.url)!, contentMode : .scaleAspectFit)
```