# image appear over UIImageView corner radius border swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, calayer, uibezierpath

when I set border width and corner radius to UIImageView and load image it appear over border
how to fix this problem

```
let viewedImage : UIImageView = {
    let img = UIImageView()
    img.layer.borderWidth = 1
    img.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    img.layer.cornerRadius = 28
    return img
}()
```

[image]

Comment: Try adding yourImageView.clipsToBounds = true

Comment: You can check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50982423/ios-uiimage-going-outside-of-uiimageview-border/50982562

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it and tell me it work or not ...

```
let viewedImage : UIImageView = {

        let img = UIImageView()
        img.layer.cornerRadius = 28
        img.layer.clipsToBounds = true
        img.layer.borderWidth = 2
        img.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        return img
    }()
```

Answer (score 3):

Set  [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622415-clipstobounds)

```
img.clipsToBounds = true
```

> Setting this value to true causes subviews to be clipped to the bounds of the receiver. If set to false, subviews whose frames extend beyond the visible bounds of the receiver are not clipped. The default value is false

Answer (score 1):

According to [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622415-clipstobounds)

> clipsToBounds property
>
> A Boolean value that determines whether subviews are confined to the
>   bounds of the view.
>
> Discussion Setting this value to YES causes subviews to be clipped to
>   the bounds of the receiver. If set to NO, subviews whose frames extend
>   beyond the visible bounds of the receiver are not clipped. The default
>   value is NO.

```
let viewedImage : UIImageView = {
        let img = UIImageView()
        img.layer.borderWidth = 1
        img.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        img.layer.cornerRadius = 28
        img.clipsToBounds = true
        return img
    }()
```